# Now able to use the XN and XO command in azcopy

Tags: windows, azure, azcopy

I am doing azure blob uploading winform application using azcopy.

In that i am able to upload and download the files.but i am need to download the blobs only based on the time of the modification so i used the /XO command as below but it does not work for me.

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:https://portalvhdsq3jyv0y3gccrn.blob.core.windows.net/sampes /Dest:C:/localblobs /SourceKey:VVPgjNO9V3397kOvoJRRZKtZVZaVNQP2xFPTNoWEp8zPJh4n487HVmwup498T8iufFnDS1Icu0EmUKyHg+DdkA== /MT /XO
```

even i tried the following command its also not working fine

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:https://portalvhdsq3jyv0y3gccrn.blob.core.windows.net/sampes /Dest:C:/localblobs /SourceKey:VVPgjNO9V3397kOvoJRRZKtZVZaVNQP2xFPTNoWEp8zPJh4n487HVmwup498T8iufFnDS1Icu0EmUKyHg+DdkA== /MT /XN
```

can any one give me suggestion

Comment: What version of AzCopy are you using? What do you mean by "not work for me"? Are you hitting error messages? Or the file transferred to destination aren't your want?